# Start work with elements in gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

At the moment there GridViewActivity, where toolbar'e posted "+" button (which adds elements gridView list).

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.addPerson) {
    addPersonToAdapter();
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The question is, is it possible the image as "+" (or whatever the xml file) to place in the top of my list gridView, where by clicking on this item add my elements so that the picture is "+" is always moved to the right?

Now i add some changes in my code

```
public int getCount() {
    return persons.size() + 1;
}
```

and want to add something like this in my method getView

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(position == getCount - 1) {
return new "my image or what??"
} else {
    return View;
}
```

Full code getView:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    person = persons.get(position);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLastNameTextView);
        viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.name.setText(person.name);
    viewHolder.photo.setImageResource(setImage());

    Button buttonDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            persons.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, have you looked at the [vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Define an enumerator and pass it as parameter to the method..

```
public enum EVideo{
    YOUTUBE,
    VIMEO

}

private void useLinkInput(String input,EVideo video ) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
    String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(videoID)) {
        String[] str = input.split("/");
        videoID = str[str.length-1];
    }
    if(video == EVideo.YOUTUBE){
        source= "http://img.youtube.com/vi/";
    }else{
        source= "http://VIMEO.CN";
    }
    url = source + videoID +"/0.jpg";
    Log.d("url",url);

}
```

Comment: bad answer! Java enums DO NOT play nicely with Android

Comment: @apelsoczi give better answer